# Basic ideal property, Let $R$ be a ring $I$ be an ideal, $IR$ and $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.
Let $I$ be $R$'s ideal.

$IR⊂I$ hold in general because $I$ is ideal but $IR=I$ does not hold in general ?
I guess $1$ does not in $IR$ sometimes, but I cannot figure out counterexample.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don’t get your reasoning. For each $a \in I$, $a=a1 \in IR$; so $I \subseteq IR$.

Comment: Oh bad, then, always $IR=R$ ?

Comment: No, $IR=I$. You observed that $IR \subseteq I$ since $I$ is an ideal, and I showed that $I \subseteq IR$.

Comment: $I=IR$ is true when $RI$ is set theoretic product or ideal product ? Both cases ?

Comment: Yes that is what I needed.

Comment: There are ideals such that $IR\ne I$; take, for example, $I = R= 2\mathbb Z$. I think a question worth considering is, what can we say about ideals (and the rings they are contained in) such that $IR = I$? There are rings without identity such that $R^2 = R$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true for both the set and the ideal product.

The ideal product is the smallest ideal containing the set product. But the set product satisfies $IR\subset I$ ($I $ is an ideal), and $IR\supset I$ ($1\in R$).  So it's $I$.

So, in summary,  when you take the product of an ideal with the whole ring (either set or ideal product) you get back the ideal.

Comment: What about $I=R=2\mathbb Z$? In general it is not true that $IR=I$.

Comment: @PhilipSpeegle $2\Bbb Z$ doesn't have a unit element.

Comment: The OP never specified that $R$ has an identity. The question is completely trivial if so. The whole point of the question, I believe, is to characterize the ideals that satisfy $IR=I$ for certain rings.